# How do I get substring after a character when the occurance of the character keeps changing

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

Example

```
123\.456.578.910.ABC
123\.456.578.910
```

Expected result

```
123\.456.578
123\.456.578
```

For the both the inputs I should get only the first 3

I tried the regexp and substring and instr but I’m not getting the results

Comment: The solutions works don’t work on teradata

Comment: Well, @MT0's solution works on Teradata

Answer (score 0):

We can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` here with a capture group:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '^(\d+(\.\d+)*)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

*Traditional*, `substr` + `instr` combination is another option:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '123\.456.578.910.ABC' from dual union all
  3     select '123\.456.578.910'     from dual
  4    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  5  select col,
  6         substr(col, 1, instr(col, '.', 1, 3) - 1) result
  7  from test;

COL                  RESULT
-------------------- --------------------
123\.456.578.910.ABC 123\.456.578
123\.456.578.910     123\.456.578

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you value will always have at least 3 `.` characters then you can use:

```sql
SELECT value,
       SUBSTR(value, 1, INSTR(value, '.', 1, 3) - 1) AS expected
FROM   table_name;
```

If it may have fewer and you want the entire string in those cases then:

```sql
SELECT value,
       CASE INSTR(value, '.', 1, 3)
       WHEN 0
       THEN value
       ELSE SUBSTR(value, 1, INSTR(value, '.', 1, 3) - 1)
       END AS expected
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT '123\.456.578.910.ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123\.456.578.910' FROM DUAL;
```

Both outputs:

> | VALUE | EXPECTED |
> | --- | --- |
> | 123.456.578.910.ABC | 123.456.578 |
> | 123.456.578.910 | 123.456.578 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6b75c683e58c0ca9d7ce9cb9503b5a69)*